# jq - unable to correctly perform multiple selects

Tags: arrays, shell, select, jq

I've been reading through other posts and jq reference pages but I cannot seem to get this working.

Example data

```
{
    "member": [
    {
        "firstName": "Paul"
        "lastName": "Simons"
        "certificates": [
            {
                "status" : "Pass",
                "grade" : {
                  "type" : "music",
                  "level" : 3
                },
            "awardDate" : "2023-01-28"
            }
            {
                "status" : "Pass",
                "grade" : {
                  "type" : "sports",
                  "level" : 2
                },
            "awardDate" : "2021-02-02"
            }
                        {
                "status" : "Pass",
                "grade" : {
                  "type" : "music",
                  "level" : 2
                },
            "awardDate" : "2021-02-02"
            }
    }
]
}
```

The aim is to list: each members name, date of most senior grade (per type), type of grade, level of grade.

```
Paul Simmons, [music, 3, 2023-01-28], [sports, 2, 2021-02-02].
```

Where I've gotten to before my head exploded:

```
jq -r '.member[] |
[.firstName + " " + .lastName, (.certificates
| sort_by(.awardDate)
| (.[-1].awardDate) as $max
| .[]
| select(.grade.type)
| select(.awardDate == $max)
| [(.awardDate | fromdateiso8601 | strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d")), .grade.type, .grade.level])'] members.json
```

Determining the most recent level (per type of certificate), could also be finding the highest level, rather than using date - however I was having trouble.

Comment: Please update your sample data to valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a JSON input like

```json
{
  "member": [
    {
      "firstName": "Paul",
      "lastName": "Simons",
      "certificates": [
        {
          "status": "Pass",
          "grade": {
            "type": "music",
            "level": 3
          },
          "awardDate": "2023-01-28"
        },
        {
          "status": "Pass",
          "grade": {
            "type": "sports",
            "level": 2
          },
          "awardDate": "2021-02-02"
        },
        {
          "status": "Pass",
          "grade": {
            "type": "music",
            "level": 2
          },
          "awardDate": "2021-02-02"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You could use `group_by` to combine same grade types, and `max_by` to get the one with the highest grade level:

```bash
.member[] | ["\(.firstName) \(.lastName)", (.certificates
  | group_by(.grade.type)[] | max_by(.grade.level)
  | "[\(.grade.type), \(.grade.level), \(.awardDate)]"
)] | join(", ") + "."
```

```
Paul Simons, [music, 3, 2023-01-28], [sports, 2, 2021-02-02].
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jD6hJzgkoHD)

Comment: Thank you.
Is there a way to ensure the output is ordered for students without certificates in some types, as below:
`Paul Simons, [music, 3, 2023-01-28], [sports, 2, 2021-02-02].
Other person, [music, null, null], [sports, 1, 1998-01-01].`

Now that I've been reading further, I see it would be better to keep the data in an object, then flatten the json using to_entries then convert to @csv.

Keen to read your thoughts.

Comment: @user3813400 How about first storing an array of all types, e.g. `([.member[].certificates[].grade.type] | unique) as $types`. Then, for each member, create an `INDEX` of their certificates, and query that by using the stored array's items (which always unfolds in the same order), e.g. `.member[] | [.firstName, .lastName, (.certificates | group_by(.grade.type) | map(max_by(.grade.level)) | INDEX(.grade.type) | $types[] as $type | [$type, (.[$type] | .grade.level, .awardDate)])]`. Here's another [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/PKI4hYLBpS9). Drop the brackets of the inner array to make it flat.

Comment: Cheers @pmf! That's really made the difference.
The only issue I have now is trying to convert the date (they're actually stored in iso8601.
`(.awardDate | fromdateiso8601 | strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d"))`
is now resulting in
`strptime/1 requires string inputs and arguments`
Haven't had an issue with the conversion until now

Comment: @user3813400 `.awardDate` from your sample data is formatted `%Y-%m-%d` but `fromdateiso8601` requires `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ`. To what format are you trying to convert it? Bear in mind that JSON does not have its own date format, it has strings (for storing a formatted date) or numbers (for storing seconds or milliseconds) etc.

Comment: That's correct. I didn't include it in the sample data to avoid complicating it further, as I already had the conversion working - I see that I had left it in my attempted original jq also.
When substituted into what's working now, .awardDate seems to be a different type - hence failing. 
`([.member[] | [.firstName, .lastName, (.certificates | group_by(.grade.type) | map(max_by(.grade.level)) | INDEX(.grade.type) | $types[] as $type | [$type, (.[$type] | .grade.level, (.awardDate | fromdateiso8601 | strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d")))])]`
Error is: `strptime/1 requires string inputs and arguments`

Comment: @user3813400 `.awardDate` is taken directly from your input. You might want to provide a default value for the `null` case, e.g. `(.awardDate | (fromdate | strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d"))? // null)`. Here's yet another [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Ymz9DQJdZmw). Apart from that, especially without providing any actual data supporting it, the issue that ".awardDate seems to be a different type - hence failing" is beyond retraceability. You might want to ask a new question explicating this very issue, together with the data needed to reproduce it.